# PHP contact form with Captcha: "failed the anti-spam check"

Tags: php, forms, captcha, spam-prevention

I'm using a Contract form from HTML Contract Form Guide in my website. In testing, I am running my website from my computer using apache and PHP v5.5. Everything seems to work well on my testing server and I can fill out the form, click submit, and land on the "success page". When I upload my site to my hosting service and try to use the contact form, the captcha does not accept my input and returns the message, "failed the anti-spam check". My hosting service is running PHP v5.3. I'm not sure what's changing and why my form no longer works when I upload it. Oh, I am also learning PHP on the fly so I might not fully comprehend what I am being asked so it might take me a little longer to give an accurate reply.

*** This issue was solved. I ended up contacting fatcow which is my hosting company. This is their response "I have set the session.save_path in your 'PHP Scripting' and I have increased the memory limit from 32 MB to 128 MB for your PHP scripts." I guess it was a server side issue. I guess I've narrowed it down and when I run to a similar issue I can also assume it is a server side issue. Hope anyone with a similar issue can use this post and decide what to do accordingly.**

I ran `var_dump()` on `$_SESSION['FGCF_Captcha_Answer']` and `$user_answer` and both values were equal. This is what I got:

string 'c85757e710d687d24c0b044812d5ee05' (length=32)

string 'c85757e710d687d24c0b044812d5ee05' (length=32)

I am also hosting from a fatcow server and have contacted them to see if they know anything about this issue with reCAPTCHA on their server. Just awaiting their reply. Is it possible that the server I'm running on could experience these things, maybe not a programming question but like I stated above, on my own computer running with apache the form works fine and the only problem I'm having on fatcow is not the entire form, just reCAPTCHA

Here is the captcha code, if anything else is needed please let me know:

```
<?PHP
    class FGSimpleCaptcha extends FG_CaptchaHandler
    {
var $error_str;
var $captcha_varname;
var $uniquekey;

function FGSimpleCaptcha($captcha_var_name)
{
    $this->captcha_varname=$captcha_var_name;
    $this->uniquekey='KHJhsjsy65HGbsmnd';
}

/*Add more simple questions here.*/
function GetSimpleCaptcha()
{
    $arrQuestions = array(
    "What color is the sky? "=>"blue",
    "What is 1+1=" => "2",
    "What is the color of grass?"=>"green",
    "Are you a robot? "=>"no",
    "Are you human?"=>"yes");

    $question = array_rand($arrQuestions);
    $answer = $arrQuestions[$question];

    $_SESSION['FGCF_Captcha_Answer'] = $this->Md5CaptchaAnswer($answer);

    return $question;
}

function SetFormKey($key)
{
    $this->uniquekey = $key;
}
function GetKey()
{
    return $this->uniquekey;
}
function Validate()
{
    $ret=false;
    if(empty($_POST[$this->captcha_varname]))
    {
        $this->error_str = "Please answer the anti-spam question";
        $ret = false;
    }
    else
    {

        $scaptcha = trim($_POST[$this->captcha_varname]);

        $scaptcha = strtolower($scaptcha);

        $user_answer = $this->Md5CaptchaAnswer($scaptcha);

        if($user_answer != $_SESSION['FGCF_Captcha_Answer'])
        {
            $this->error_str = "Failed the anti-spam check!";
            $ret = false;
        }
        else
        {
            $ret = true;
        }
    }//else
    return $ret;
}
function Md5CaptchaAnswer($answer)
{
    return md5($this->GetKey().$answer);
}
function GetError()
{
    return $this->error_str;
}
}
?>
```

Here is partial code for the form:

```
    class FGContactForm
{
var $receipients;
var $errors;
var $error_message;
var $name;
var $email;
var $message;
var $from_address;
var $form_random_key;
var $conditional_field;
var $arr_conditional_receipients;
var $fileupload_fields;
var $captcha_handler;

var $mailer;

function FGContactForm()
{
    $this->receipients = array();
    $this->errors = array();
    $this->form_random_key = 'HTgsjhartag';
    $this->conditional_field='';
    $this->arr_conditional_receipients=array();
    $this->fileupload_fields=array();

    $this->mailer = new PHPMailer();
    $this->mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';
}

function EnableCaptcha($captcha_handler)
{
    $this->captcha_handler = $captcha_handler;
    session_start();
}

function AddRecipient($email,$name="")
{
    $this->mailer->AddAddress($email,$name);
}

function SetFromAddress($from)
{
    $this->from_address = $from;
}
function SetFormRandomKey($key)
{
    $this->form_random_key = $key;
}
function GetSpamTrapInputName()
{
    return 'sp'.md5('KHGdnbvsgst'.$this->GetKey());
}
function SafeDisplay($value_name)
{
    if(empty($_POST[$value_name]))
    {
        return'';
    }
    return htmlentities($_POST[$value_name]);
}
function GetFormIDInputName()
{
    $rand = md5('TygshRt'.$this->GetKey());

    $rand = substr($rand,0,20);
    return 'id'.$rand;
}


function GetFormIDInputValue()
{
    return md5('jhgahTsajhg'.$this->GetKey());
}

function SetConditionalField($field)
{
    $this->conditional_field = $field;
}
function AddConditionalReceipent($value,$email)
{
    $this->arr_conditional_receipients[$value] =  $email;
}

function AddFileUploadField($file_field_name,$accepted_types,$max_size)
{

    $this->fileupload_fields[] =
        array("name"=>$file_field_name,
        "file_types"=>$accepted_types,
        "maxsize"=>$max_size);
}

function ProcessForm()
{
    if(!isset($_POST['submitted']))
    {
       return false;
    }
    if(!$this->Validate())
    {
        $this->error_message = implode('<br/>',$this->errors);
        return false;
    }
    $this->CollectData();

    $ret = $this->SendFormSubmission();

    return $ret;
}

function RedirectToURL($url)
{
    header("Location: $url");/* Redirect browser */

    /* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
    exit;
}

function GetErrorMessage()
{
    return $this->error_message;
}
function GetSelfScript()
{
    return htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

function GetName()
{
    return $this->name;
}
function GetEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}
function GetMessage()
{
    return htmlentities($this->message,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
}
```

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` in your code? You need that if you're going to be using $_SESSION.

Comment: @andrewsi yes I do. I will try and input some of the code from the form so you can see what I'm working with.I try not to inundate you with code so I take a snippet of it out.

Comment: You'd be surprised at how often people forget it. In that case - the message you're getting seems to come up as a result of failing this check: `if($user_answer != $_SESSION['FGCF_Captcha_Answer'])`. Could you try using `var_dump` on both of those variables, so you can see what the values actually are?

Comment: @andrewsi I've never used that before. Been looking through the forums to properly implement `var_dump()` but I'm not sure where I am supposed to put it to get a result. I tried the console.

Comment: It should go in your code, right above that `if` statement. You just need to add `var_dump($user_answer);` and `var_dump($_SESSION['FGCF_Captcha_Answer']);`, and add the output to your question; re-run the code, and it'll print out the values of those variables. When you're debugging, `var_dump()` is invaluable.

Comment: @andrewsi I had to get away for a bit but I'm back at it again.I'm not sure what you meant in your last comment "and add the output to your question". I put the code you provided above the if statement `if($user_answer != $_SESSION['FGCF_Captcha_Answer'])` in the captcha file. I reran the file and filled out the form and then got a warning message about the header. I figured I did this wrong. could you break down your direction a bit more. My PHP experience is showing.

Comment: What I mean was, add those lines to your code, right above the `if` statement. When you re-run the code, it will output some extra text on your form - it will show you exactly what the values are. Then, you can edit your question here, and paste those values into it.

Comment: @andrewsi I've provided more information to my original post with the values from `var_dump()` they are both equal and I'm starting to think it's a server side issue if that's even possible but you would know more about that. If there is an alternate to what I'm trying to do then I can get rid of the reCAPTCHA altogether and go with any other suggestions that would save me from spam bots.

Comment: Well. That's just weird - those are indeed identical, so your if statement should be coming out as true. Is it definitely `Failed the anti-spam check!` that's coming up? What if you change the if statement to `if ($user_answer != $user_answer)` - if you compare a variable to itself, it's got to pass, so we can see if there's an issue elsewhere.

Comment: @andrewsi thanks for all your help man. I ended up solving the problem by contacting fatcow. Never new it could have been with them. I've edited my question appropriately.

Comment: Well. I would never have thought of that being an issue - I'm glad you got it sorted! You should post that as an answer yourself, and accept it when you're able.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved. I ended up contacting fatcow which is my hosting company. This is their response "I have set the session.save_path in your 'PHP Scripting' and I have increased the memory limit from 32 MB to 128 MB for your PHP scripts." I guess it was a server side issue. With some help I was able to narrow it down and when I run to a similar issue I can also assume it is a server side issue. Hope anyone with a similar issue can use this post and decide what to do accordingly.